# Send transaction at a specified future slot

Tags: send-transaction

Is it possible to send a transaction at a specified slot in the future? I have tried playing around with the minContextSlot variable in the send transaction config options, but that seemingly will wait until the specified slot has been processed before allowing the transaction to be sent. But usually this will result in the transaction actually landing several slots after the specified slot. Is there a precise way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an external service, this is not possible in most cases.  You have a few options:

- send your transaction a few slots before the one you want. This requires listening to slot updates on the chain in order to broadcast at the right time, and doesn't ensure that your transaction will land in that slot.
- use an MEV client which allows you to purchase block space from a validator, and in return they guarantee to include your transaction when they are leader

Comment: So in the second case, said MEV client would need to be working with every validator that produces blocks to guarantee you could get a transaction processed at a certain slot I imagine.

Comment: In the easiest case for you, yes. If 60% of stake weight uses it, then you could land it in 60% of slots etc etc

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Clockwork](https://www.clockwork.xyz/). It's an automation engine that should fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the mention! The scheduler is currently based off the unix timestamp rather than slots, but we are scoping out slot-based schedules and will be rolling out that feature very soon.

Comment: Got it. Keep leading from the front!